# Como puedo conservar el mismo alto y ancho para todas las imágenes y que sean responsivas sin deformarsen

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

Deseo que todas las imagenes tengan la misma altura y la conserven tan cual aparece en la imagen que anexo, pero deseo darles un poco más de ancho y de iguala forma que no dejen de ser responsivas, no se deformen y no pierdan la definición.

He tratado colocandoles algo de css y no he podido:

### **detalle.componenet.css**

img {
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}

### **detalle.component.html**

```
<div class="col-sm">
      <img *ngIf="cliente?.foto" src="http://localhost:9090/api/uploads/img/{{cliente.foto}}" alt="{{cliente.foto}}" class="img-thumbnail rounded">
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

*Bootstrap 4* tiene la clase [img-fluid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/) para hacer las **imagenes responsive**, lo que hace es aplicarle a la imagen un `max-width: 100%;` y un `height: auto;`

Y poniendo a la imágen la clase `h-100` conseguirías la misma altura en todas que sería el alto del contenedor

Answer (score 1):

probablemente ocupes hacerlo por medio de una ventana gráfica (ViewPOrt), te paso este articulo.
[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

De igual manera deberias de meterte al diseño responsive en esa misma pagina hay un pequeño curso de  diseño responsivo

Comment: Hice lo siguiente a nivel del html, puse las clases que me indica en la linea de la etiqueta img, a nivel de mozilla quedan iguales, pero chrome se alarga la imagen y se sale de la página aunque me gustaría aunmentarles el ancho, el alto esta bien en mozilla no pasa igual para chrome:           <img  *ngIf="cliente?.foto" src="http://localhost:9090/api/uploads/img/{{cliente.foto}}" alt="{{cliente.foto}}" class="img-thumbnail rounded img-fluid h-100"> y si le quito el css que tengo el archivo se deforman las imágenes.  img {
  max-width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
}